# Findroot and plot not showing line

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I need help solving this equation

$$2- 12 sin(3 x) - 6 x = 0$$

using `FindRoot`, but it does not seem to work.

For example,

```
NFindRoot[2 - 12 sin[3 x] - 6 x == 0, x].
```

I also need help with plotting of a different task.

I have

`Arean = Solve[{A == xy, x^2 + y^2 == (2 r)^2, r == 3}, {A, y, r}]`

and I need to plot it but the line doesn't show up.

I tried

```
Plot[A /. Last[Arean], {x, 0, 4}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "A"}, 
 PlotStyle -> Green]
```

Comment: `FindRoot` needs a starting search point. Also it is `Sin` not `sin`. Try `FindRoot[2 - 12 Sin[3 x] - 6 x == 0, {x, 0}]` and you get a root. If you plot it, you see where approximatly the roots are. `Plot[2 - 12 Sin[3 x] - 6 x, {x, -3, 3}]`

Comment: I suggest that you ask two different questions since they are so different in spirit. I believe that this is the general approach here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the first part of your post, there are a number of mistakes. If you try

```
FindRoot[2 - 12 Sin[3 x] - 6 x == 0, {x, 1}]
```

you can get an answer.

The mistakes were that you should have used `Sin` instead of sin and the proper way to write the command is `FindRoot`

For the second question:

There is a mistake in your code and this is why the plot is not showing. You did not leave a space between the variables `x` and `y`

Try the following

```
Arean = Solve[{A == x y, x^2 + y^2 == (2 r)^2, r == 3}, {A, y, r}]

Plot[A /. Last[Arean], {x, 0, 4}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "A"}, 
 PlotStyle -> Green]
```

Answer (score 2):

for the first part, you can first find the solutions

```
sol = Flatten[
  Table[FindRoot[2 - 12 Sin[3 x] - 6 x == 0, {x, i}], {i, -2, 2}]]
{x->-1.6325,x->-1.39504,x->0.047759,x->1.19582,x->1.81603}
```

and then you can check these solutions as follows

```
  ContourPlot[{2 - 12 Sin[3 x] - 6 x == y, y == 0}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -1, 
      1}, Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[5], 
       Point[Table[{sol[[i, 2]], 0}, {i, 5}]]}]
```

[image]

the solutions are the red dots.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `Solve` or `NSolve`.

```
NSolve[2 - 12 Sin[3 x] - 6 x == 0, x, Reals]
```

> `{{x -> -1.6325}, {x -> -1.39504}, {x -> 0.047759}, {x ->  1.19582}, {x -> 1.81603}}`

```
Plot[2 - 12 Sin[3 x] - 6 x, {x, -6, 6}, MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, 
 Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> Red]
```

[image]